# Remove entries from NSMutableDictionary based on match on NSString value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

After a network call to the Instagram API, I get back a responseDictionary NSDictionary delegate with the following Key/Value structure:

```
{
data =     (
            {
        bio = "Los Angeles/Orange County Realtor\U00ae \n\U6d1b\U6749\U77f6\U623f\U5730\U4ea7\U7ecf\U7eaa\U4eba\nCall/Text/WhatsApp: (310) 717-1321\nEmail: Jxxxcom\nWeChat (\U5fae\U4fe1): xx";
        "full_name" = "xx yy (\U7530\U4f73\U6dfc) Rx Realty";
        id = 25354408;
        "profile_picture" = "http://scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpa1/outbound-distillery/t0.0-20/OBPTH/profiles/profile_xxx_75sq_1391378894.jpg";
        username = jxxi;
        website = "http://www.Jxghty.com";
    },
```

The profile_picture key often has an NSString value that contains anonymousUser (for the users who didn't set any profile pictures).

I am looking to remove those entries from my responseDictionary as follows:

```
        //Create mutable copy of IG responseDictionary
        NSMutableDictionary *dictCleanAvatars = [responseDictionary mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"Log dictCleanAvatars after mutableCopy IG response: %@", dictCleanAvatars);

        NSArray *keys = [dictCleanAvatars allKeys]; //get all the keys
        NSUInteger k2 = [dictCleanAvatars count];
        NSLog(@"k2 in dictCleanAvatars before cleanup is: %lu", (unsigned long)k2);

        for (int i = 0; i<k2; i++)
        {

            if ([[dictCleanAvatars objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                //if its an NSString - don't want an exception if its another type of object
                NSLog(@"Yes, objectAtIndex:i us Kind ofClass NSString for i = %d", i);

                if ([[dictCleanAvatars objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]] rangeOfString:@"anonymousUser"].location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Yes, anonymousUser identified in objectAtIndex:i for i = %d", i);
                    //if object has the key word im looking for
                    [dictCleanAvatars removeObjectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]]; //remove the key
                    NSLog(@"That's dictCleanAvatars after loop %d: %@", i, dictCleanAvatars);
                }
            }
        }
```

But this doesn't work.

Would value feedback from more experience iOS developers.

Comment: "But this doesn't work" is not a description of a problem.

Comment: why don't you use KVC to find and remove your key like data. dictionary.valueForKey(@"data.Anonymous") ? and later try to make remove using the same path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to build an array that includes everything from the `data` key's array, but omitting those dictionaries for which `profile_picture` contains the string "AnonymousUser", you can use `NSPredicate`:

```
NSArray *dataArray = responseDictionary[@"data"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not (profile_picture contains 'AnonymousUser')"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Or you can use `predicateWithBlock`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject[@"profile_picture"] rangeOfString:@"AnonymousUser"].location == NSNotFound;
}];
```

BTW, if you already have a mutable array, you can also remove entries from it using `filterUsingPredicate`, using the above predicates:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableDataArray = [responseDictionary[@"data"] mutableCopy];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not (profile_picture contains 'AnonymousUser')"];
[mutableDataArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

---

If, on the other hand, you don't want to remove entire dictionaries from the array of dictionaries, but rather want to simply remove the occurrences of `profile_picture` for which "AnonymousUser" is present, you want to ensure that not only is the array mutable, but so are its constituent dictionaries.

The easiest way of doing this is to specify the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option when parsing the JSON. Then you can just iterate through the `NSMutableDictionary` entries, removing the `profile_picture` entries with a `profile_picture` with "AnonymousUser" in them:

```
NSMutableDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSMutableArray *mutableDataArray = responseDictionary[@"data"];

for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in mutableDataArray) {
    NSString *profilePicture = dictionary[@"profile_picture"];
    if ([profilePicture rangeOfString:@"AnonymousUser"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [dictionary removeObjectForKey:@"profile_picture"];
    }
}
```

If, however, you can't specify the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option when you parse the JSON and are stuck with a immutable collection, you need to make a mutable copy of it. Unfortunately, a simple `mutableCopy` of the array won't make the member dictionaries mutable themselves, but you can use a Core Foundation call to `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy` to make a mutable array with mutable entries, which you can then modify:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableDataArray = CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFArrayRef)responseDictionary[@"data"], kCFPropertyListMutableContainers));
```

Then you can use the above `for` loop, iterating through this array's dictionary entries, removing the offending `profile_picture` entries.

Comment: Hi Rob:  I opted for the third option.  Love the conciseness.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[dictCleanAvatars objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]] isEqualToString@"anonymousUser"] {
```

The problem is, suppose [dictCleanAvatars objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]] is not an NSString?  You might want to check for that first.

Answer (score 0):

If the only field you are looking at is profile_picture, I would go with a less generic approach which is much more readable and understandable

This code works for me

```
- (void)testExample
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"data": @[ @{ @"bio": @"blah blah", @"profile_picture": @"some stuff anonymousUser other stuff" },
                                              @{ @"bio": @"some other object", @"profile_picture": @"some other profile picture link" }] };
    // dictionary is a mock of the data you provided

    NSArray *data = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    for (NSDictionary * avatarDict in data) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mdict = [avatarDict mutableCopy];
        id ppid = [mdict objectForKey:@"profile_picture"];
        if ([ppid isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            NSString *pp = (NSString *)ppid;
            if ([pp rangeOfString:@"anonymousUser"].location != NSNotFound) {
                [mdict removeObjectForKey:@"profile_picture"];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"altered dictionary: %@", mdict);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2014-08-13 10:53:36.727 test[11981:60b] altered dictionary: {
    bio = "blah blah";
}
2014-08-13 10:53:36.728 test[11981:60b] altered dictionary: {
    bio = "some other object";
    "profile_picture" = "some other profile picture link";
}
```

Comment: Won't that just delete the entry from the copy of the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, hes not going to be able to delete it from the immutable original.